# How to display selected item from drop down using html, css and javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a drop down list where list of countries is being fetched from JSON array. Drop down list is coming from dynamic json object. I have applied search in that drop down list. I am trying to display the selected item but I am unable to do it. I want that when I select a particular country from the list it get displayed.

```js
function myFunction() {
  var country = [{
      "ID": "001",
      "Country_Name": "India"
    },
    {
      "ID": "002",
      "Country_Name": "Australia"
    },
    {
      "ID": "003",
      "Country_Name": "Austria"
    },
    {
      "ID": "004",
      "Country_Name": "China"
    },
    {
      "ID": "005",
      "Country_Name": "Bangladesh"
    }
  ];
  document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
  var ele = document.getElementById("myDropdown");
  for (var i = 0; i <= country.length; i++) {
    ele.innerHTML = ele.innerHTML + '<a value="' + country[i]['ID'] + '">' + country[i]
      ['Country_Name'] + '</a>';
  }
}

function filterFunction() {
  var input, filter, ul, li, a, i;
  input = document.getElementById("myInput");
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  div = document.getElementById("myDropdown");
  a = div.getElementsByTagName("a");
  for (i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    txtValue = a[i].textContent || a[i].innerText;
    if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
      a[i].style.display = "";
    } else {
      a[i].style.display = "none";
    }
  }
}
```

```css
#myInput {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-image: url('searchicon.png');
  background-position: 14px 12px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 14px 20px 12px 45px;
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
}

#myInput:focus {
  outline: 3px solid #ddd;
}

position: relative;
display: inline-block;

}
.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f6f6f6;
  min-width: 230px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  z-index: 1;
}
.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}
.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #f1f1f1
}
.show {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown">
  <button onclick="myFunction()" class "dropbtn"> Dropdown </button>
  <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content" onclick="show()">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Search..." id="myInput" onkeyup="filterFunction()">
    <a value=""></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I've combined your code blocks into a snippet and there seem to be a few console errors when you interact. Could you update the snippet to reproduce the exact issue you are trying to solve?

Answer (score 0):

Your code had a couple of errors:

- `<div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content" onclick="show()">` but show() is not defined so I removed the onclick handler;
- `for (i = 0; i <= a.length; i++)` should be instead `i < a.length`

Plus I better refactored the part where you built the anchor elements so that instead of using the `innerHTML` strategy, those elements get created with `document.createElement()`. That way there's the chance to have a reference to the object and add a click event handler to each option, so that when you click a Country, its name gets displayed on console.

The country option click handler was defined as the `countryOnClick()` function and so far it justs displays the clicked option data on console. You are free to change it anyway you like to perform the action you better prefer.

Each option will have the class `dropdown-option` and when an option is selected will have the class `optionSelected`. To query the document and know which option got selected, this is the css selector:

`document.querySelector('#myDropdown > .dropdown-option.selectedOption')`

```js
function myFunction() {
  
  var country = [
      {
        "ID": "001",
        "Country_Name": "India"
      },
      {
        "ID": "002",
        "Country_Name": "Australia"
      },
      {
        "ID": "003",
        "Country_Name": "Austria"
      },
      {
        "ID": "004",
        "Country_Name": "China"
      },
      {
        "ID": "005",
        "Country_Name": "Bangladesh"
      }
  ];
  
  document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
  var ele = document.getElementById("myDropdown");
  
  //for each country in the country array
  for (var i = 0; i < country.length; i++) {  
    //creates an anchor element 
    const countryOption = document.createElement("a");
    //holding the country ID in its value attribute
    countryOption.setAttribute('value', country[i]['ID']);
    //and the country Name as its innerText
    countryOption.innerText = country[i]['Country_Name'];  
    //adds the class dropdown-option to the option element
    countryOption.classList.add('dropdown-option');
    
    //binds the countryOnClick function defined below as its click event handler
    countryOption.addEventListener('click', countryOnClick);
    
    //appends the new anchor to the dropdown element
    ele.appendChild(countryOption);      
  }
}

//click event handler for the dropdown options
function countryOnClick(event){  

  //fetch country properties from the element triggering the event
  const clickedOption = event.target;
  const countryID = clickedOption.getAttribute('value');
  const countryName = clickedOption.innerText;
  
  //removes the selectedOption class to every option in the dropdown
  clickedOption.closest('div').querySelectorAll('.dropdown-option').forEach((o,i)=>{
    o.classList.remove('selectedOption');
  });
  //adds the selectedOption class to the selected option element
  clickedOption.classList.add('selectedOption');
  
  //show those data on console
  console.log(`${countryID} - ${countryName}`);
  
  console.log( getSelectedOption() );
}

function getSelectedOption(){
  return document.querySelector('#myDropdown > .dropdown-option.selectedOption');
}

//gets called when the filter input changes, and it filters the dropdown options list
function filterFunction() {   
  var input, filter, ul, li, a, i;
  input = document.getElementById("myInput");
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  div = document.getElementById("myDropdown");
  a = div.getElementsByTagName("a");
  for (i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    txtValue = a[i].textContent || a[i].innerText;
    if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
      a[i].style.display = "";
    } else {
      a[i].style.display = "none";
    }
  }
}
```

```css
#myInput {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-image: url('searchicon.png');
  background-position: 14px 12px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 14px 20px 12px 45px;
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
}

#myInput:focus {
  outline: 3px solid #ddd;
}

position: relative;
display: inline-block;

}
.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f6f6f6;
  min-width: 230px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  z-index: 1;
}
.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}
.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #f1f1f1
}
.show {
  display: block;
}

.dropdown-content > .dropdown-option{
  cursor: pointer;
}

.dropdown-content > .selectedOption{
  background-color: darkgray !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown">
  <button onclick="myFunction()" class "dropbtn"> Dropdown </button>
  <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Search..." id="myInput" onkeyup="filterFunction()">
    <a value=""></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Here when some country is searched, related country get filtered out. So what I want is that when that filtered country is clicked it get displayed..

Comment: can you please better explain what did you exactly mean by saying: when the filtered country is clicked it gets displayed? So far you have a simil-dropdown that gets displayed when you click the "Dropdown" button, showing all its available options coming from the country array. Then when you type something inside the input text, the options get filtered (so only countries matching the typed text will be shown). Now how you want the country showed when you click on it? you didn't mention any further details about it anywhere both here in your comment and in your question

Comment: I edited my question with a better strategy to build the country option elements, with a click event handler on all of them and with further comments explaining the logic. But it's up to you to define what does it mean to show the clicked option.